# How to display empty disk space

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

If `du -hs` displays the disk usage, how can I know the `empty` space as well?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you want to know how much Disk free?

```
df -h
```

Disk space is divided into partitions, so `du` isn't going to show how much space is available.

Comment: df -h|awk '{print $1,$4,$NF}'|column -t # is a hack shorthand for humans

Comment: This approach might be confusing if zfs is used though.

Comment: The use of awk and column is unnecessary with "df -h --output=source,avail,target"

Comment: @jlliagre could you tell us the answer for zfs?

Comment: @RamanSailopal the "`--output`" option is not available with all "df" implementations.

Comment: @Alex Using `df` would still give available space per file system under zfs. The issue is that space might vary without anything created or deleted on that file system because the disk space is shared between all file systems and volumes stored in the same zfs pool. The `zpool list` command gives the overall available space in the column labeled `FREE`. When quotas are set on file systems, interpreting `df` output is also slightly more complex.